# Brachistochrone Problem for Inhomogeneous Potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, brachistochrone-problem

[This recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/if-it-was-possible-to-dig-a-hole-that-went-from-one-side-of-the-earth-to-the-othe) about holes dug through the Earth led me to wonder: if I wanted to dig out a tube from the north pole to the equator and build a water slide in it, which shape would be the fastest?

We're assuming a frictionless tube, of course.  Let's ignore centrifugal forces.  Coriolis forces do no work, and so shouldn't matter.  Also, let's assume the Earth is a sphere with uniform density.

I tried to solve this problem by writing down an integral in polar coordinates for the time, then applying the Euler-Lagrange equations.  However, I didn't make any progress on the resulting differential equation.  Is there an analytical expression for the curve?

Comment: Sounds interesting, what's the functional?

Comment: It seems like this article should be relevant: H. L. Stalford and F. E. Garrett, "Classical differential geometry solution of the brachistochrone tunnel problem", Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications, Volume 80, Number 2, 227-260, http://www.springerlink.com/content/f21724177qxptn56/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, the curve is a a hypocycloid.

See for instance:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SphereWithTunnelBrachistochrone/

http://www.physics.unlv.edu/~maxham/gravitytrain.pdf

Comment: More from Wolfram: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherewithTunnel.html http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html

Comment: (The first of my three Wolfram links is just for the ordinary Brachistochrone problem + friction.)

Comment: If one weights the optimal trajectory with a function of the length and depth of the tunnel - i.e. real construction costs - then the best solution tends to the straight line arc. Time of travel along such arcs are constant - about 42 minutes each. Building such a network doesn't seem too unreasonable.