# Fastest path for a gravity train

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, speed, brachistochrone-problem

On [wikipedia > gravity train](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_train), the time to go from any point `A` to any point `B` at the surface of the earth (assuming earth is a perfect sphere and absence of friction) by a straight line takes a constant ~42 minutes.

[image]

Intuitively, I would expect that a fastest path would be curved and pass closer to the center of the earth.

**What is the fastest path between two points `A` and `B` with a gravity train?**

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7421/2451 and links therein.

Comment: My question is indeed a duplicate! Thanks. Should I delete my post and let people close it?

Comment: Leave it as is. Your post is clearly written, and it may help others as a stub/bookmark.