# Expected behavior of the gravity under some experiment

Tags: gravity, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, centrifugal-force, free-fall

I would like to know the **expected behavior** of the **Gravity** under the following mentioned **imaginary experiment**:

What if we dig a **well** or a **boar** or a **straight hole** (say, its diameter is **100** meter) **throughout the earth** (i.e. Start digging from the one end of the Earth until you reach the exact opposite end of the Earth) and then one heavy and rigid **spherical stone** (say, its diameter is **1** meter) is to be **fallen down** into that well or boar or hole? What would **happen** to that **sphere**?

Assume all the **best conditions** for this experiment: a perfect round-shaped well with no inner disturbances, sphere is made from the very hard material, a perfect vertical free-fall of the sphere, etc.

How long would it travel through this well?

Will sphere **stop its journey** by reaching the **center of the earth**?

If yes, then could you **justify this situation** by the various **forces applying** on that sphere **at that time**?

Please share your views and justifications on this experiment.

Comment: *Hint: think about simple harmonic motion.*

Comment: related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7346/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/

Answer (score 0):

Let the center of the earth lie at the origin, and let $r$ denote radial position.  The gravitational force in the sphere will be
$$
  \mathbf F = -\frac{G\mu(r)m}{r^3}\mathbf r
$$
where $\mu(r)$ represents the mass contained in the subsphere of the Earth with radius less than $r$;
$$
  \mu(r) = \frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3}M = \frac{r^3}{R^3}M
$$
Using Newton's second law, this gives the following equation of motion:
$$
  \ddot{\mathbf r} = -\frac{GM}{R^3} \mathbf r
$$
Now contemplate Will's comment.

Comment: The mass of Earth, $M$, is missing in the last two formulas, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well If the ball will not take any type of resistance then it will just oscillate from one end of the well to other end forever.