# Earth's graviational pull at the centre

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets, projectile

Suppose, I somehow happen to dig a hole diametrically through the Earth (neglecting all constraints like molten core etc ) ... and I throw an object from one side of the hole, will it reach the other end?

Comment: Yeah sure, if you ignore air friction and the rotation of the Earth and assume the Earth is a perfect sphere then you can drop it and it will fall all the way to the surface of the other side, and oscillate back and forth.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7346/2451 and links therein. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2481/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Mass is responsible for gravity , why would it pass the centre if there is where the max mass exist ?

Comment: No one says the mass ***is*** st the center;  they say that ***mathematically***, you can treat the spherically distributed mass ***as if it were*** at the center, and get the correct result...

Answer (score 2):

Drill through the spin axis, or the vacuum free fall trajectory scrapes the side from Coriolis force.  Other than that,

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/earthole.html