# Motion of a ball in a tunnel along Earth's diameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, earth, planets

Suppose, a tunnel is made along the diameter of Earth and we drop a ball inside it. How will the ball behave? Please help me understand.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7346/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

It will oscillate around the center of Earth. 
To find the equation you will need to solve the generic oscillation problem:
the gravity force / acceleration depends on the distance to Earth's center while everything which is further from the center will not impact on the acceleration.

1. $g(x)=G\cdot M(x)/x^2$;
2. $M(x)=\mathrm{average~earth~density}\cdot 4/3\cdot \pi \cdot x^3$
3. $g(x)=-\omega^2\cdot x$

I let you to calculate the rest.

Comment: 2. The density of earth is far from uniform, so the formula for $M(x)$ isn't right. 3. What is $\omega$?

Comment: The density of the Earth was uniform when I was asked to solve the problem for a high-school physics homework assignment.