# What if we jump into center of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, earth, planets

[image: Tunneled Earth]

What if we dug a tunnel through the center of the earth connecting the two ends (like two poles).
Suppose we have these condition in our tunnel.

1:There is no heat at all.

2:The tunnel be vacuumed (there is no air resistance in it).

**Questions**
1:What if we jump through this tunnel what would happen then?

2:Can we reach the other end of the earth?

3:If yes, How long it would take to reach the other end point?

4:Can we survive through the journey (if the above conditions are applied)?

5:If there is air at the center what would be the pressure at center?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7346/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Their are plenty of articles and videos on internet explaining this. I suggest this video to begin with explaining it very simply: https://youtube.com/watch?v=jN-FfJKgis8

Comment: Gravity train: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_train#Diametric_path_to_antipodes

Comment: If there is no friction. You will go in simple harmonic motion as you reach the center. Basically, you will go up and down forever.

Comment: @LostCause I think the radial density variations would lead to a slight deviation from simple (mono-frequency) harmonic motion.

Comment: I assumed uniform density, which would enable me to use center of mass. I just did some back of the envelope calculations and I found that the mass doesn't matter. The equation becomes the SHM equation with frequency sqrt(g/a), and half-time of around 42minutes. The maximum speed at the center would be around 8km/s. I don't have the proper keyboard or I would have shared the equations.