# What will be the nature of motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets

If a piece of matter is released along the tunnel extended between one end to the opposite end through the diameter of the earth, what will be the nature of motion?

Comment: @Qmechanic Now? It would be better if you edit my question because I have asked two question one is similar to the one you mentioned , what about second question ?

Comment: Let's see what the reviewers say. Also you might want to check out the links in the [duplicate Phys.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7346/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic what reviewers said ?

Comment: [3 x Leave closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/211481).