# Digging a hole in the moon across its diameter

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets

What will occur if one digs a hole in some moon/dead-planet without an atmosphere (and without a Lava Core), such that this hole shall have a 1 meter diameter and will be so deep that shall go through its core and appear on the other side of the moon?

Then one shall jump (or drop a ball) into that hole.

Will the object simply reach the other side of the planet/moon at speed of 0? Thus a harmonic motion from side to side of the planet?

Addition: Differences from [If it was possible to dig a hole that went from one side of the Earth to the other...](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/if-it-was-possible-to-dig-a-hole-that-went-from-one-side-of-the-earth-to-the-oth):

1. This is vacuum (no atmosphere)
2. I drop an object and do not jump inside the hole

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7346/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Lecture on the subject: https://youtu.be/s8UrYIZhm60?t=2707 From stanford university - shows this is harmonic motion

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but asides the Harmonic motion well it also depends on the Gravity of the dead core(**without lava**), given it's somewhat active . If it were hypothetically possible to spoon dip a big hollow hole through the moon the Newtonian concept of gravity may have the core's gravity influenced or destroyed but if one considers the space fabric concept of Gravity well I certainly cannot say for a fact what might happen. But Newton's 2nd Law holds that a body would continue in its state of motion or rest except if altered(well in this case the gravity of the dead hollow core would be the altering agent).

> **P.S** There's likely to be a Gravitational anomaly if we get to swiftly bore up a hole through a planet's core. Hence one can't be certain for sure as to what exactly would happen.

Comment: I have no idea what this answer is trying to say, but I suspect it's not based on our current understanding of physics.

Comment: It looks like you're saying that the body will travel straight at an unchanged velocity; that's completely wrong: you'll actually see something resembling SHM. More importantly, it's important to not digress to the unimportant point of what the other effects the construction of such a hole may have (and that too make an ambiguous claim regarding that), and focus on the question as asked.

Comment: I don't totally agree. because I believe the question can only have a speculative or objective answer if its without any limitations on unlikely events occuring. boring up a hole passing through a planet's core could for one reason result in unknown certainties such as the possibility of the the core imploding, the core engulfing the planet or the core creating gravitational anomalies.

Comment: If the anomalies/uncertainties causes the core to loose it's Gravitation with the planet still intact  then Newton's second law would be applicable to the question. If not then I agree with the SHM of the object.  No one has ever done it so to predict or say exactly event X would occur when it hasn't been done  would only be... some giant scientific speculation with some bogus mathematical evidence to cap it off(given you have a bunch of equations to support the claim).

Comment: BTW Newtonian Gravity assumed space was flat while Einstein's holds that space was curved and could as well bend light. If the object is dropped through the hole I don't believe it's motion would be the same if one considers both concepts of Gravity differently.

Comment: e.g. lets assume its possible to jump/drop the object through the hole at WAP speed? What would be the motion of the object be like?